Visual Studio Code Enter button does not work
I just installed the newest version of VScode 1.88.0 x64
I read another post I do not have the addon that has
vscode-styled-components

I have also added this line to the setting file
editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "smart"

I have gone through key binding and removed just about every single Enter bind Except these below
New Line and auto indent (This one exists 3 times)
acceptRenameInput

I really don't know what else I can do to get my enter to work normally. I have restarted VScode and computer quite a few times. This is really frustrating. Is there any why to fix or isolate the issue to it can be addressed?

does the enter key work in other applications?

The enter key works just fine just not in Vscode. Not sure if thats what your asking.

In what context?  Are you saying if you open a file and type abc<enter>def, that you do not get two lines?

Backup and clean your settings.json and keybindings.json. Restart VSC with --disable-extensions to temporarily turn off extensions.

I removed the Settings.json and the keybindings.json files so new files were created I also disabled all Extensions. The Enter button is still a bit problematic as it works once every time I hit enter 3-4 times.
